# Increasing online exposure

Tags: seo, advertising, google-ads, business

Hello fellow Webmasters.

I'm looking for some advice from the more veteran or more aware users out there. So I been managing my step-fathers company for about 1 year now. We are a very small "Plumbing" company based in Ontario, Canada. I'm more skilled with writing websites and code as it's something I been doing as a hobby since high school and pretty good at it, but I have absolutely no experience in putting the company out there.

We have hired few different SEO companies truthout the years and most of them offered us no results within a reasonable timeframe of 6 mon to 1 year. As such what are some pointer of getting the business out there, and having it attract more customer rather than collect dust somewhere on xxxxxxxx page of Google or burning money on AdWord.

I don't understand SEO and things, but I tried following articles and such but in the end of the day that does not seem to matter and we can't exactly afford $1000/mon SEO package. I even purchased 2 SEO books from Amazon and still nothing. As of now we are paying $1000 for Google AdWord and honestly we aren't showing on Google much and we aren't getting the much needed Calls.

It's getting to the points where I feel like one of this days I will just be in a corner sucking my thumb, as all the effort and work I been putting in just seems to be spitting back into my face.

With that said what suggestions would you have?

Kindly thank you.

Comment: Other than Adwords and paying SEO idiots, what have you done? As it is, this question is far too broad to answer without actionable information. Any of us can help you. We are real experts. Many of the so-called SEO experts are only expert at sucking money out of your nether regions. We, on the other hand, can offer real help that is effective and can be improved upon. However, we do need a jumping off point. Afterall, we cannot rewrite the books you already have read. Cheers!!

Comment: As Closenoc said, avoid the SEO snake oil sellers

Comment: @closetnoc I added business to G Maps, Bing Business, variety of directories, we are on Yelp, FB, TW, YT and on a site called HomeStars (reviews). I used to write Blog posts under our site, giving tips and stuff but have stopped doing so, and I would usually put links to this stuff to G+, FB, TW. And I believe I added the site to Directories around the web. About it.

Comment: @closetnoc I have also did some heavy work on website to be fast and meet A rating, also added SSL and the site runs on Bootstrap so its mobile friendly. Load times are around 2 to 2.5 seconds. Outside of that site uses custom build CMS that I did in php and uses friendly url slugs like /24-hour-emergency-plumbing or /drain-services and ect. I added url to the site im talking about feel free to check it out.

Comment: @Steve I would if I knew bit more how to put our business out there, I never got around seo stuff. Always been good old amature php coder.

Comment: Here is some of what links do not work and what does: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/18643/is-link-building-a-white-hat-seo-activity/86906#86906 Here is some branding stuff: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/71489/google-excluding-site-for-queries-for-its-exact-name/71493#71493 and http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/86266/local-tld-vs-com-and-com-nl-vs-nl/86268#86268 Here is a short list of trust metrics: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/69127/how-to-get-google-pagerank-from-the-toolbar-to-increase-from-0/69140#69140

Comment: This is a few of the key knowledge graph card signals: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/99933/how-do-you-get-google-to-show-wiki-information-about-your-site-in-the-right-side/99953#99953 Here is some on semantics: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/81551/why-would-a-website-with-keyword-stuffing-rank-higher-than-one-without-in-google/81552#81552 Here is some on featured snippets: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/102180/what-factors-probably-contributed-for-this-appearance-in-google-featured-snippet/102188#102188

Comment: Here is a detailed answer to my own question about comments and ratings: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/91804/what-value-do-comments-and-ratings-have-anymore/91839#91839 Here is one on URL paths (slugs): http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/74633/well-structured-urls-vs-urls-optimized-for-seo/74639#74639 That is enough to keep you up at nights! I can find more. But that is enough to begin. You are doing some of this already. Pay attention to semantics. Pay attention to the headline read order. Pay attention to links; internal, external, inbound. Cheers!!

Comment: BTW- Specific questions are best. As you think of things, if we can help, please ask. You can also use the search function. Just make sure what ever SEO advice you follow is recent. Keep in mind that most SEOs online are just parroting junk. As well, most SEOs are non-technical people and have no clue about the technologies used in search engines. Look for people that have more than a clue. Stop paying for SEO if you do (unless it is one of our guys). [insert cheese eating grin] Come here first before jumping in and implementing something new to make sure it is a good idea.

Comment: As closetnoc indicates, this is unfortunately too broad a question. Questions here really need to focus on a single issue or problem, and individual SEO or website reviews are considered off-topic since they're unlikely to help others in the future. Check out the [frequent](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=frequent) questions we have on the site related to SEO, such as [this](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-a-sites-position-in-google) one.